# NetConnection failed

Tags: flash-media-server, netconnection

I recently downloaded Adobe media server starter 5.0. I am unable to connect to FMS using rtmfp. I keep receiving the NetConnection.Connect.Failed error. When i run it locally things appear to be working fine.

I have checked ports 80, 443, and 1935 and they are all open.

How should i diagnose this.
What are the common causes of this problem?

Thank You.

Comment: When you receive the `NetStatusEvent` `NetConnection.Connect.Failed` what does the `event.info.description` property say?

Comment: You should also make sure that port 1935 is open for UPD, as RMTFP is a UDP protocol (RTMP (no 'F') is TCP). For others running into problems like this there is also the RTMPT protocol which will use HTTP to get through firewall restrictions on "non standard" ports.